# How to sent POST request to Django from external app

Tags: python, django

I am trying to sent post request from python script which works on Windows machine.

Here is my views.py Django

```
def check(request):

    if 'login/password' in request.POST:
        checkdata(request.POST)
    else:
        message = '404'
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

And here is my post.py

```
param_tuples = [('login', 'value1'), ('pass', 'value2')]
response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/check', data=param_tuples)
```

The problem is that Django reject my request because i dont have csrf token

```
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /check
```

How can i get csrf token in order to sent request to Django server externally ?

Comment: if you want your app to allow programmatic logins, you would have to decorate your view with `@csrf_exempt`. But this is a security risk in production if you don't have any other protection like IP-whitelisting or the like.

Comment: @schwobaseggl
Well yea,it will be executed only from 1 pc. But how can i apply "csrf_exempt" only to one "check" function? If ill write csrf_exempt in views.py it will disable csrf for all functions,isnt it?